# Android- Image not getting loaded

Tags: java, android, android-studio, picasso

When I click on an image in our project, another image gets loaded. It works fine, but when I go back to the previous activity, and click on the same image, it doesn't get loaded.

This is the first activity which opens when app is active. This page will show grid of pictures

```
public class GentsActivity extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    //Web api url
    public static final String DATA_URL = "PHP LINK HERE";

    //Tag values to read from json
    public static final String TAG_IMAGE_URL = "small_image_url";



    //GridView Object
    private GridView gridView;

    //ArrayList for Storing image urls and titles
    private ArrayList<String> images;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Returning the layout file after inflating
        //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gents, container, false);

        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        getData();
        //swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        images = new ArrayList<>();


        //Calling the getData method


        /*swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // Your code to refresh the list here.
                // Make sure you call swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false)
                // once the network request has completed successfully.
                //Toast.makeText(this,"refresh ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent mIntent= new Intent(SareeActivity.this,SareeActivity.class);
                startActivity(mIntent);
                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        });*/

        return view;
    }

    private void getData(){
        //Showing a progress dialog while our app fetches the data from url
        //final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait,","Fetching data.",false,false);

        //Creating a json array request to get the json from our api
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Dismissing the progressdialog on response
                        //              loading.dismiss();

                        //Displaying our grid
                        showGrid(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        );

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        //Adding our request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }



    private void showGrid(JSONArray jsonArray){
        //Looping through all the elements of json array
        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            //Creating a json object of the current index
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                //getting json object from current index
                obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Log.d(TAG_IMAGE_URL,"JSON SHOW GRID"+obj);
                //getting image url and title from json object
                images.add(obj.getString(TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                Log.d(TAG_IMAGE_URL,"JSON SHOW GRID"+images);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //Creating GridViewAdapter Object


        //Adding adapter to gridview
        GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getContext(),images);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }





    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String prompt = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        Intent mIntent= new Intent(getActivity(),LoadPhotoGents.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("s",prompt);
        startActivity(mIntent);


    }
}
```

When I click on a particular photo, that single photo will open. The code is given below

```
public class LoadPhotoGents extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String data, path;
    private ImageView ivi;
    public static final String DATA_URL = "PHP LINK HERE";
    private static int id=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_photo_gents);

        data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("s");
        path = data.replace(".JPG", "big.JPG");
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Path:" + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        ivi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullImage);
        Picasso.with(LoadPhotoGents.this).load(path).into(ivi);
        getData();
        ImageViewTouch img = (ImageViewTouch) findViewById(R.id.fullImage);
        img.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        ivi.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmap=ivi.getDrawingCache();
        //img.setFitToScreen(true);
        img.setImageBitmap(bmap);

    }


    private void getData(){
        String url=DATA_URL+data.trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(url,new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response){

                showJSON(response);

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response){

        String name= "";
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);

            //JSONArray result= jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
            JSONObject datas=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            name=datas.getString("description");



        }catch(JSONException e){
            Toast.makeText(this,"inside getData: "+name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will definitely help you to debug the issue. In your code I can see that you are loading the image directly using `Picasso.with().load().into()` problem with this method is you do not know what is happening at the background.

You can do two things. First use `Callback` when you load the image into the ImageView as below

```
Picasso.with(LoadPhotoGents.this).load(path).into(ivi, new Callback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess()
                    {
                        Timber.d("Image Loaded Successfully");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError()
                    {
                        Timber.d("Error Loading Image");
                    }
                });
```

Above can be used to handle image loaded/not loaded scenario.

Now coming to the actual error while loading the image, you need to use a `Picasso.Builder` which has a listener which will help you know the actual error.

Build Picasso Builder as below

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(mContext);
builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
    {
        Timber.d(exception.getMessage());
    }
});

Picasso pic = builder.build();
```

To Load the image do the following

```
pic.load(path).into(ivi, new Callback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess()
                {
                    Timber.d("Image Loaded Successfully");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError()
                {
                    Timber.d("Image Load Error");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that path variable is not null or empty

Comment: Path is not null, first click works.. when I go to previous activity and click again it's not working. In cosole it's not showing Null also